# Neo4j: Match three or more relationships to a single dynamic node

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying out Neo4j for a personal project to implement a recommendation system.  The system takes several strings as Input and Outputs a recommendation.  The system has nodes in the form of Animals and Groups.  The relationship between animals and groups is that an animal belongs to a group.  An animal can belong to multiple groups.

The input can be any number of animals.  The question I am attempting to answer is "Which animals are present in the groups that contain all the input animals?"

An example of correct output:

```
Input: Lion, Parrot, Giraffe
Output: Elephant, Zebra
The lion, parrot and giraffe all belong to group 2 and 3.  The elephant belongs to group 2 and the zebra belongs to group 3, so they are outputted.
```

My current solution:

```
 Match (:Animal { name: "Parrot" })
            -[:BELONGS_TO]->(matchingGroup:Group)
            <-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Animal { name: "Lion" }),
        (:Animal { name: "Giraffe" })
            -[:BELONGS_TO]->matchingGroup
            <-[:BELONGS_TO]-(animalsInMatchingGroup:Animal)
    Return animalsInMatchingGroup.name AS name, count(animalsInMatchingGroup.name) as matches
    ORDER BY count(animalsInMatchingGroup.name) DESC
```

The Problem:
The problem arises when I have more than two animals in my query.  In the query above I am querying the graph using Match statements equal to the number of input animals - 1.  I am wondering if anyone knows of a better solution to this problem that will prevent querying the graph multiple times.

This is the graph.
http://s29.postimg.org/inhhvqcd3/Screen_Shot_2014_10_05_at_8_09_23_PM.png

Create statement

```
CREATE 
(elephant:Animal { name: 'Elephant' }),
(lion:Animal { name: 'Lion' }),
(tiger:Animal { name: 'Tiger' }),
(giraffe:Animal { name: 'Giraffe' }),
(parrot:Animal { name: 'Parrot' }),
(zebra:Animal { name: 'Zebra' }),
(group1:Group { name: 'Group 1' }),
(group2:Group { name: 'Group 2' }),
(group3:Group { name: 'Group 3' }),
(group4:Group { name: 'Group 4' }),
(group5:Group { name: 'Group 5' }),
elephant-[:BELONGS_TO]->group2,
elephant-[:BELONGS_TO]->group3,
lion-[:BELONGS_TO]->group1,
lion-[:BELONGS_TO]->group2,
lion-[:BELONGS_TO]->group3,
parrot-[:BELONGS_TO]->group2,
parrot-[:BELONGS_TO]->group3,
parrot-[:BELONGS_TO]->group5,
giraffe-[:BELONGS_TO]->group2,
giraffe-[:BELONGS_TO]->group3,
giraffe-[:BELONGS_TO]->group4,
tiger-[:BELONGS_TO]->group5,
zebra-[:BELONGS_TO]->group4,
zebra-[:BELONGS_TO]->group3
```

Thanks for your help.

Cheers, Cam.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WITH ['Parrot', 'Lion', 'Giraffe'] AS names
MATCH (:Animal { name: head(names)})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(g:Group)
WITH g,names
MATCH (g)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(a:Animal)
WITH g,collect(a.name) AS animals,names
WHERE ALL (n IN names 
           WHERE n IN animals)
RETURN g.name, animals,names,size(animals)
```

See this console: http://console.neo4j.org/r/vd2mba

Comment: There are some good ideas in this query, but the output is wrong.  Thank you for the insight, I'll see if I can shorten the query using the WITH parameter.

One question: Does using the IN clause suffer the same performance hit when using it in a SQL statement?